# C++ set with a comparator for sort and another for uniqueness

Tags: c++, comparator, stdvector, stdset

Edge is a class with 3 fields: weight, from_vertex, to_vertex. I want to create a set containing all unique edges in a graph. (If from_vertex and to_vertex are swapped -and weights are equal-, it is still the same edge.) Also, I want this set be sorted by weights of the edges. Is this possible with a set implementation or is there a better way?

Comment: A `std::set` uses the fact that it's sorted to more quickly find if an element already exists in the set. It couldn't rely on this if sorting was done with a different predicate from the uniqueness predicate.

Comment: Would you consider two edges equal if from_vertex and to_vertex are the same but the weight is different?

Comment: @jpw no, weights must be equal too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, it's possible. But only because you don't actually need two comparators.

The basic idea is to lexically sort on the tuple `<weight, min_vertex, max_vertex>`, where `min_vertex` is the lesser of `to_vertex` or `from_vertex`, and `max_vertex` is the greater. Two opposing edges with the same weight will have the same tuple, of course, and two opposing edges *without* the same weight will be distinct. The set will overall be sorted by weight, since that's the most significant element of the tuple.

One thing that this *doesn't* get you is the ability to search for an edge if you know the `from,to` but don't know the weight. Similarly, it doesn't make all the edges for a particular `from,to` pair consecutive (which, of course, would be incompatible with sorting by weight). If you want that sort of thing, you'll probably need to maintain multiple structures.